# Laravel Spark: "All My Teams" Billing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

As I understand it, Laravel Spark has two billing modes.

The first is individual billing.  In individual billing, each user account is responsible for signing up for and paying for its own service.

The second is team billing.  In team billing, you can sign up all the users on an individual team for plan.

If either of the above are incorrect assumptions, please let me know.

What I need/want to do might be called "All My Teams" or "Team of Teams" billing.  I need an administrative user to be able to create multiple teams with different users, and have all those users managed (for billing purposes) under a single subscription.

Is this possible with Laravel Spark?

If not, is there known science for how to do this?  Get as detailed as you'd like, but I'm just looking for the broad strokes here, and trying to to duplicate work if it already exists.

Comment: below a proposed solution, not mine but based on the amount of times your work with magento helped me I felt in the obligation to find an answer in our  laravel community. brgds

Comment: additionally, here you will find many projects for laravel spark https://github.com/jpmurray/awesome-spark

Answer (score 2):

Alan, In [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/spark-multiple-teams) the offer the following solution for you question:

> Yes it does and you can limit it in 3 ways from the owning account
>   perspective:
>
> ```
>     ->maxCollaborators($max)
>     ->maxTeams($max)
>     ->maxTeamMembers($max) Users can create as many teams as they want (unless you limit it as mentioned above) and they can also join
> ```
>
> other people's teams if they are invited.

hope it helps!